# How to grab selected dates from flatpickr

Tags: javascript

I have a range date picker at the moment.

```
<input id="rangeDatepicker2" class="g-font-size-12 g-font-size-default--md" type="text" data-rp-wrapper="#rangePickerWrapper2" data-rp-type="range" data-rp-date-format="d M Y" data-rp-default-date='["01 Jan 2016", "31 Dec 2017"]'>
```

I would like to reuse the dates but I am unable to select them for all scenarios. I tried the code below which works great if the date selected are in the same month. But my issue is this bit of code doesn't work if the dates span multiple months.

```
$("#rangeDatepicker2").change(function () {
    var dates = $('.selected');
    if (dates.length == 2) {
        var start = dates[0].dateObj;
        var end = dates[1].dateObj;

        //interact with selected dates here
    }
});
```

May I ask how do I properly grab selected date range of a flatpickr.

[image]

Comment: Can you add your initialization code? Where you make your "#rangeDatepicker2" a flatpickr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many input plugins actually pass the values in a `onChange` handler. The values are available there.

### Solution

Pass down an `onChange` handler when initializing **flatpickr**:

```
$("#rangeDatepicker2").flatpickr({
    mode: 'range',
    onChange: function(dates) {
        if (dates.length == 2) {
            var start = dates[0];
            var end = dates[1];

            // interact with selected dates here
        }
    }
})
```

### Demo

[image: Edit confident-breeze-ge534]

*`onChange` documentation:*
https://flatpickr.js.org/events/#hooks

Comment: weird, the function flatpickr is not recognized.

Comment: How would you change the date format of start and end?